# Building a combined package for 32-bit and 64-bit using rpmbuild

Tags: linux, rpm

I have a combined package for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux platform.

On 64-bit system, all files are getting installed whatever mentioned in the %files section of the spec file.(Both 32-bit and 64-bit files).
On 32-bit system also, all files are getting installed whatever mentioned in the %files section of the spec file but 64-bit files are removed during postinstall(I wrote a code for removal).

The problem is, on 32-bit machine, package manager displays all files when queried to display the files installed by the package. So 64-bit files being displayed on 32-bit machine.(eg rpm -ql)

Is there any good way to remove 64-bit files on 32-bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to do it. RPMs are designed to have 32- and 64-bit machines treated as separate architectures, and for good reason. **You should be building two RPMs.**

By taking it upon yourself to delete files you just installed within your `%post` section, you are creating errors in the RPM database.  As you noted, `rpm -ql` lists the files as being there (according to the DB, they *should* be there). For another example, now any `rpm -V` verification of your RPMs will be broken - the files you purposely erased are considered missing by the system. `rpm -Va` (verify all packages) is something that many people do before attempting an OS upgrade, and the user will think they need to re-install your RPM.

Comment: Is there any way to update rpm DB about removed files of package, so that i can get only available files when queried with rpm -ql.

Comment: Could you please explain what's the value of "%ifarch" macro in spec file. to build a package we have to pass "--target <arch>" (say i386) to rpmbuild cas parameter. If so, is the value of %ifarch will become i386. Otherwise %ifarch is the architecture of machine on which we are building the package OR is the architecture of machine on which we are installing the package?

Comment: What about if you're building RPMs that have a buildarch=`noarch`? What about RPMs for interpreted languages like Perl? Do you still need to build a 32-bit and a 64-bit version? Is `noarch` to be avoided then?